# Create transducer from ordinary code

Tags: clojure

How would I create a transducer from the following ordinary code, where `combo` is the alias for `clojure.math.combinatorics`:

```
(defn row->evenly-divided [xs]
  (->> (combo/combinations (sort-by - xs) 2)
       (some (fn [[big small]]
               (assert (>= big small))
               (let [res (/ big small)]
                 (when (int? res)
                   res))))))
```

As noted in a comment transducers are only applicable for processing each item. With this is mind I've made the code a little more transducer friendly by shifting the sorting so that it is now being done for each item. I don't think there's anything that can be done about the combinations part however!

```
(defn row->evenly-divided [xs]
  (->> (combo/combinations xs 2)
       (some (fn [xy]
               (let [res (apply / (sort-by - xy))]
                 (when (int? res)
                   res))))))
```

Comment: I think it's a little bit awkward to apply a transducer here if you want to combine all `combinations` step, `sort` step, and `evenly divided` step into a process. To create combinations and sort them, one needs to traverse the whole list and pair with other items. While the transducer assumes each item is processed individually before accumulating. Aside from that, IMO, the `some` here is perfectly fine performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same function but with an introduced transducer:

```
(def x-row->evenly-divided (comp
                             (map (partial sort-by -))
                             (map (partial apply /))
                             (filter int?)))

(defn row->evenly-divided-2 [xs]
  (->> (combo/combinations xs 2)
       (sequence x-row->evenly-divided)
       first))
```